# Accessing a member of a Class where the thread is created

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple classes that have a common variable with the same name.
Say a string variable "str".

I have a thread class say "thread_update_str"

What I need to do is make the str variable in the class from which it is called to the current  datetime from the method run of the thread.

Could anyone help me figure how could I achieve something like this
Any help would be appreciated ...

Thanks a lot

### Also I do not necessarily need the value of str to be same across all classes.

```
Class abc
{
    String str = "a";
    new str_Thread().start();
    System.out.println(str);
}

Class xyz
{
    String str = "x";
    new str_Thread().start();
    System.out.println(str);
}

Class lmn
{
    String str = "l";
    new str_Thread().start();
    System.out.println(str);
}

public class str_Thread extends Thread {

public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
        try {

            //make the str variable equal to i.toString();
            sleep((int)(10000));

        System.out.println("DONE!"+i);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier for us to give you specific advice if you were to show us your actual code instead of describing it.

Comment: Let me get this straight: do you need to access the `str` string inside the thread code and then again in the class that created the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes should implement an interface with the method

```
void setStr(String str);
```

And your thread-class gets the object where to set the String as constructor arg.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a common interface like this

```
 public interface ThreadCallback{
     public void setStr(String value);
 }
```

And have a constructor like this in your `str_Thread`

```
public str_Thread(ThreadCallback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

All you need to do is implement the interface and call `setStr()` from `run()`